# Month wise data in sql pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with below data.

```
Ref YEAR    MONTH   CONF_DATE   Active_Customer_Count   Role_name
43132_43252 2018    2   2/1/2018    492                 Call Center
43132_43252 2018    2   2/1/2018    113                 Others
43160_43252 2018    3   3/1/2018    1562                Call Center
43160_43252 2018    3   3/1/2018    394                 Others
43191_43252 2018    4   4/1/2018    1297                Call Center
43191_43252 2018    4   4/1/2018    517                 Others
43221_43252 2018    5   5/1/2018    2065                Call Center
43221_43252 2018    5   5/1/2018    679                 Others
43252_43252 2018    6   6/1/2018    4470                Call Center
43252_43252 2018    6   6/1/2018    662                 Others
```

I want this to be in the below format.

```
2018    
2   605
3   1956
4   1814
5   2744
6   5132
2018 Total  12251
```

Can this be done with sql pivot?

I have done this but the output is not coming month-wise.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[month]) 
            FROM #Active2 c 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT year, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select*
                from #Active2 
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 SUM(Active_Customer_Count)
                for [month] in (' + @cols + ') 
            ) p '
execute(@query)
```

Output:

```
year    2   3   4   5   6
2018    492 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2018    113 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2018    NULL    1562    NULL    NULL    NULL
2018    NULL    394 NULL    NULL    NULL
2018    NULL    NULL    1297    NULL    NULL
2018    NULL    NULL    517 NULL    NULL
2018    NULL    NULL    NULL    2065    NULL
2018    NULL    NULL    NULL    679 NULL
2018    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4470
2018    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    662
```

Comment: Your desire results do not make sense as a SQL result set.  A SQL result set has a fixed number of columns, the same number of columns all all rows.

Comment: Why use PIVOT at all? The results look like a simple `GROUP BY Year,MONTH`, possibly with a `WITH ROLLUP` clause to calculage the year total

Comment: @panagiotis That makes sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #t

;WITH CTE(Ref ,[YEAR],[MONTH], CONF_DATE,  Active_Customer_Count, Role_name)
AS
(
SELECT '43132_43252',2018, 2,'2/1/2018', 492  ,'Call Center' UNION ALL
SELECT '43132_43252',2018, 2,'2/1/2018', 113  ,'Others'      UNION ALL
SELECT '43160_43252',2018, 3,'3/1/2018', 1562 ,'Call Center' UNION ALL
SELECT '43160_43252',2018, 3,'3/1/2018', 394  ,'Others'      UNION ALL
SELECT '43191_43252',2018, 4,'4/1/2018', 1297 ,'Call Center' UNION ALL
SELECT '43191_43252',2018, 4,'4/1/2018', 517  ,'Others'      UNION ALL
SELECT '43221_43252',2018, 5,'5/1/2018', 2065 ,'Call Center' UNION ALL
SELECT '43221_43252',2018, 5,'5/1/2018', 679  ,'Others'      UNION ALL
SELECT '43252_43252',2018, 6,'6/1/2018', 4470 ,'Call Center' UNION ALL
SELECT '43252_43252',2018, 6,'6/1/2018', 662  ,'Others'
)
SELECT * INTO #T FROM CTE

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT  [YEAR],
        ISNULL(CAST([MONTH] AS VARCHAr(10)),'Total') AS [MONTH],
        SUM(Active_Customer_Count) Active_Customer_Count 
FROM #T
GROUP BY [YEAR],[MONTH]
WITH ROLLUP
)dt 
WHERE [YEAR] IS NOT NULL
```

Demo result:http://rextester.com/PNRDX57012